# how do i change the alignment of yii framework pager?

Tags: php, yii

```
 <?php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
 'itemView' => '_view',
 'ajaxUpdate' => true,
 'pager' => array(
 'class' => 'CLinkPager',
  ),
 'template' => '{pager}{items}',
 ));
 ?>
```

after executing this the pager components are displaying as column format.is their any way to change that into row format?

Comment: Not sure I understand are you saying labels on the Y axis and each data entry is a new column on the X axis?

Comment: just like..\n prev\n next \n 1 \n 2 \n 3 \n back \n last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you getting this widget through `renderPartial()` method. When using the `renderPartial()` method controller not sending js and css files with response by default. If you want to get response with these files you should pass `true` in fourth parameter:

```
$this->renderPartial('myView',array(), false, true);
```